# Will $AB$ be always equal to $AC$ in this case?

Tags: geometry

As the picture shows, in $\triangle ABC$, $D$ is on $AB$ and $E$ is on $AC$, $AD=AE$, $DC$ and $EB$ interact at $F$, $FB=FC$.

Question: Whether it's always true that $AB=AC$? If it's always true, please explain it in steps, otherwise, give a counter example.

I tried to solve it, but found it hard to prove any conclusions.

[image: picture]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple proof:

Noticing that the problem can be seen as this: There is an isosceles triangle BFC, and we extend BF to point E and CF to point D, we want to prove that AD=AE is always equivalent to AB=AC. And what controls the lengths of all of them is FD and FE.

If DF=EF, it's easy to prove that AB=AC, and vice versa. So AB=AC is equivalent to DF=EF. Now we want to prove that DF=EF is equivalent to AD=AE.

Without loss of generality, let's assume DF>EF. Connect DE, we must have $\angle DEF>\angle EDF$.

Next, let's consider $\angle AEB$ and $\angle ADC$. $\angle AEB=\angle ACB+\angle EBC$, $\angle ADC=\angle ABC+\angle BCD$. Because $\angle EBC=\angle BCD$, their difference $\angle ADC-\angle AEB= \angle ABC-\angle ACB$, which must be positive, because we can choose a point $G$ on $DF$ such that $GF=EF$ and $\angle GBC=\angle ECB$. This shows that $\angle ABC>\angle ACB$. So we have $\angle ADC>\angle AEB$.

Combined with $\angle DEF>\angle EDF$, we get $\angle ADE>\angle AED$, $AE>AD$. Similarly, $AE<AD$ if $DF<EF$. So $AE=AD$ only if $DF=EF$. The proof that $DF=EF$ is equivalent to $AD=AE$ is complete.